# Connecting Java to mysql Error

Tags: java, mysql

So I'm trying to connect my java code to mysql and when I run the code below nothing prints out not even the error. I'm following a YouTube tutorial and understand everything except where he is getting "jdbc:mysql:" from. Any help would be awesome thanks.

```
package ztestconnection;

import java.sql.*;

public class Test {

static String Username = "Klongrich";
static String Password = "********";
static String Connection = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/hospital";

public static void main(String [] args){

    Connection con = null;

    try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(Connection, Username, Password);
        System.out.println("Connected");
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }  

}
```

Comment: Don't post your actual database password on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Wait..did you really call a string `Connection`?  This is the name of JDBC class.  This must be causing unnice things to happen.  Did your code even _compile_?

Comment: You need to register the Driver class before get connection.

Comment: @Rugal Not since 2007.

Answer (score 0):

To connect java application with the `mysql` database `mysqlconnector.jar` file is required to be loaded.

1:- Download the mysqlconnector.jar file. Go to jre/lib/ext folder and paste the jar file here.

```
 //STEP 1. Import required packages
    import java.sql.*;

    public class FirstExample {
       // JDBC driver name and database URL
       static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
       static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP";

       //  Database credentials
       static final String USER = "username";
       static final String PASS = "password";

       public static void main(String[] args) {
       Connection conn = null;
       Statement stmt = null;
       try{
          //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

          //STEP 3: Open a connection
          System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

          //STEP 4: Execute a query
          System.out.println("Creating statement...");
          stmt = conn.createStatement();
          String sql;
          sql = "SELECT id, first, last, age FROM Employees";
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

          //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
          while(rs.next()){
             //Retrieve by column name
             int id  = rs.getInt("id");
             int age = rs.getInt("age");
             String first = rs.getString("first");
             String last = rs.getString("last");

             //Display values
             System.out.print("ID: " + id);
             System.out.print(", Age: " + age);
             System.out.print(", First: " + first);
             System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
          }
          //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
          rs.close();
          stmt.close();
          conn.close();
       }catch(SQLException se){
          //Handle errors for JDBC
          se.printStackTrace();
       }catch(Exception e){
          //Handle errors for Class.forName
          e.printStackTrace();
       }finally{
          //finally block used to close resources
          try{
             if(stmt!=null)
                stmt.close();
          }catch(SQLException se2){
          }// nothing we can do
          try{
             if(conn!=null)
                conn.close();
          }catch(SQLException se){
             se.printStackTrace();
          }//end finally try
       }//end try
       System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }//end main
    }//end FirstExample
```

Comment: I followed the code above and it still just keeps running and never prints off that it is trying to connect or anything.

Comment: Have you placed .jar file for database? What it is printing else?

Comment: The above code uses some table of database,you have to change them according to your database credentials,DB Name,tables etc.
I have tested this on my machine,it works fine.

Comment: Yes I have the jar file added to the program and I also did change the names according to my database. It just continues to run and doesn't print anything.

Comment: Is is giving any Error or Exception?

Answer (score -1):

Before you can open a connection, you need to load the specific driver class, like so:

```
try
{
    // The newInstance() call is a work around for some
    // broken Java implementations
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // handle the error
}
```

This ensures that `java.sql.DriverManager` can find the driver class definition.

There's some good example code in the [MySQL Connector/J documentation.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html)

As for the `jdbc:mysql:` part of the DSN (Data Source Name), that's a standard syntax that tells the driver manager and the database that they're opening a JDBC connection to a MySQL database. It will be explained in the [Oracle Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html).

And Tim has a good point about your variable names. Don't give a variable the same name as a class. Even if it doesn't confuse the compiler, it'll confuse the hell out of the maintenance programmer (you) about a week from now.